# Validation accuracy drops with ResNet50 augmented training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to train a ResNet50 from scratch on Imagenette https://github.com/fastai/imagenette

I started by just directly training and had the result below:

[image: Plain training accuracy] [image: Plain training loss]

Orange: training dataset. Blue: validation dataset.

I was quite happy with that. As you can see the training accuracy achieves over 90% but the validation maxes out around 60%, clearly not generalizing completely / over fitting.

To improve the generalization I added augmentation. An example of the augmentation is below. The original image is on the left, the augmented image is on the right.

[image: Source image] [image: Augmented image]

As you can see, the augmentaton is quite strong, but still easily human understandable. The augmentation is varied randomly on each sample and also between epochs. The validation data are not augmented. The augmentations are:

- Position
- Size
- Rotation
- Pixel channel brightness (noise)
- Overall brightness

The results from training with augmentation are below:

[image: Augmented training accuracy] [image: Augmented training loss]

Results on the training dataset seem good to me. This does appear to have improved generalization as I am getting higher top validation accuracy scores compared to the un-augmented images. However as you can see there are many severe drops in validation accuracy, down to random chance. This behavior seemed to be present without augmentation but is now a lot worse. Is this a sign of a well known problem? I would be very grateful for any help.

I have not tried to do anything unusual with this training, it's meant to be a basic ResNet50. My hyperparameters are:

- Framework: TensorFlow 2
- Optimizer: Adam
- Learning rate: 0.001
- Batch size: 64
- Regularization: L2 with parameter 0.001

Comment: are you using a reasonable validation batch size (also 64)? if you validate on your training data, do you get the same behavior?

Comment: Thank you @shimao I will check these things out first.